# Fix program that checks word for occurrences of 2 characters next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my program to check for a string for instances of 2 characters from a list that are next to each other in the string, and return a different string to replace those two characters with.

def main():

```
dubs = ["ai", "ae", "ao", "au", "ei", "eu", "iu", "oi", "ou", "ui"]
newdubs = [ "eye", "eye", "ow", "ow", "ay","eh-oo", "ew", "oy", "ow","ooey"]

word = input("ENTER WORD : " )
count = 0
fin = []
while count < len(word):

   if word[count:count+2] in dubs:

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[0]:
            fin.append(newDubs[0] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[1]:
            fin.append(newDubs[1] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[2]:

            fin.append(newDubs[2] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[3]:
            fin.append(newDubs[3] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[4]:
            fin.append(newDubs[4] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[5]:
            fin.append(newDubs[5] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[6]:
            fin.append(newDubs[6] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[7]:
            fin.append(newDubs[7] + "-")

        if word[count:count+2] == dubs[8]:
            fin.append(newDubs[8] + "-")

       if word[count:count+2] == dubs[9]:
            fin.append(newDubs[9] + "-")

    if word[count:count+2] not in dubs:
        fin.append(word[count])

    count+=1
fin= "".join(fin)

print(fin)
```

with a word like `wanai` i expect `wan-eye`
the result is `waneye-i`
I also need to run checks to see if the character before the `dubs` are a vowel, but not worrying about that until this works properly

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` + `replace()`:

```
dubs = ["ai", "ae", "ao", "au", "ei", "eu", "iu", "oi", "ou", "ui"]
newdubs = [ "eye", "eye", "ow", "ow", "ay","eh-oo", "ew", "oy", "ow","ooey"]

s = 'wanai'
for x, y in zip(dubs, newdubs):
    s = s.replace(x, f'-{y}')

print(s)
# wan-eye
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd restructure your code to be more modular:

```
dubs = ["ai", "ae", "ao", "au", "ei", "eu", "iu", "oi", "ou", "ui"]
newdubs = [ "eye", "eye", "ow", "ow", "ay","eh-oo", "ew", "oy", "ow","ooey"]

def dubbizer(word):
   for itter in range(len(dubs)):
       word = word.replace(dubs[itter], "-"+newdubs[itter])
   return word

print(dubbizer("wanai"))
```

This should give you the output of `wan-eye`

Without replace:

```
dubs = ["ai", "ae", "ao", "au", "ei", "eu", "iu", "oi", "ou", "ui"]
newdubs = [ "eye", "eye", "ow", "ow", "ay","eh-oo", "ew", "oy", "ow","ooey"]

def dubbizer(word):
   for itter in range(len(dubs)):
     while dubs[itter] in word:
       word = word[:word.find(dubs[itter])]+"-"+newdubs[itter]+word[word.find(dubs[itter])+len(dubs[itter]):]
   return word

print(dubbizer("wanai"))
```

Comment: any other way to do this w/o replace()? Thanks

Comment: @Togoneforgood I don't see why you'd want that but I added that. Check the answer again.